# Rails ActionMailer configuration for Zoho

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, zoho

Anyone have luck configuring ActionMailer to send email via a Zoho account?

These are my settings:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.zoho.com",
    :port                 => 465,
    :domain               => 'example.com',
    :user_name            => 'steve@example.com',
    :password             => 'n0tmypa$$w0rd',
    :authentication       => :login
}
```

However, calling .deliver times out:

```
irb(main):001:0> AdminMailer.signup_notification('asfd').deliver
Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:929:in `recv_response'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:552:in `block in do_start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:939:in `critical'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:552:in `do_start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:144:in `deliver!'
```

The [help docs](https://zohomail.wiki.zoho.com/Configure-in-Outlook.html) say to use port 465 and SSL authentication.  I've tried with and without `:enable_starttls_auto => true` but it still times out.

Specifically, the [docs](https://zohomail.wiki.zoho.com/Configure-in-Outlook.html) specify the following settings:

```
>     Email Address: Username@yourdomain.com
>     User Name format: Username@yourdomain.com
>     Secure Connection (SSL)   Yes
>     Outgoing Mail Server Name: smtp.zoho.com
>     Outgoing Port No.: 465
>     Outgoing Mail Server requires authentication: Yes
```

Any ideas?

p.s. I've configured Outlook to use the settings in the [help docs](https://zohomail.wiki.zoho.com/Configure-in-Outlook.html) and outgoing email works fine.  telnet to smtp.zoho.com 465 also connects.

Comment: are you trying from your localhost???

Comment: I am, though of course the SMTP server is remote (zoho.com).  Would this matter?    Email client (outlook) with the same settings is also on the same localhost..

Comment: Not sure if you want to use Outlook, Microsoft doesn't seem to condone  outgoing mail from applications - even for necessary things like email confirmations.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
# Action Mailer
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp  
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {            
  :address              => "smtp.zoho.com", 
  :port                 => 465,                 
  :user_name            => 'someone@somewhere.com',
  :password             => 'password',         
  :authentication       => :login,
  :ssl                  => true,
  :tls                  => true,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true    
}
```

That worked for me. Your settings might be fine some local networks block these kinds of packets. I had to test it through my 3G network.

Comment: left out the delivery_method.  :S

Comment: If you received the EOFError message, you may be trying to use a from address that is not an actual account in Zoho. Check this link for more information: https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/zoho-smtp.html#alink4

Answer (score 4):

FYI:

Let's say your domain is abc.com.
Let's say you have 'default from' on your mailer with a different domain, e.g.

```
  default from: "\"Elephant\" <el@ephant.com>"
```

This **will not work** unless you change your 'default from' using the same domain on your zoho account.
So,

```
  default from: "\"Elephant\" <el@abc.com>"
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Zoho have changed their security settings, but [@Tyrel Richey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2027395/tyrel-richey)'s accepted answer didn't work for me. However, the following does:

`/config/initializers/action_mailer.rb`..

```
# ActionMailer email configuration
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => ENV['SMTP_ADDRESS'],
  :port                 => ENV['SMTP_PORT'],
  :domain               => ENV['SMTP_DOMAIN'],
  :user_name            => ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'],
  :password             => ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication       => :login,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Where..
`:address` = `smtp.zoho.com`
`:port` = `587`
`:domain` is `localhost` in development, and the live URL in production (e.g. `example.com`)

Comment: your port should be 465. set ssl and tls to true.

Answer (score 0):

I have mail sending with Rails 4.2.3 like so...

```
# config/environments/development.rb
Rails.application.configure do
#...
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'domain' }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: 'smtp.zoho.com', port: 465, user_name: 'username@domain.com', password: 'mypassword', authentication: :login, ssl: true }
end
```

You can of course use this in production as well by adding this to `config/environments/production.rb`

I also set the email address in `config/initializers/devise.rb` so I can send password reset instruction.

```
config.mailer_sender = 'noreply@truhawk.com'
```

---

**References**

- https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/zoho-smtp.html
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

These settings worked for me in production.

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'eyehawk.io'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'eyehawk.io' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.zoho.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => "zoho.com",
      :user_name            => "admin@eyehawk.io",
      :password             => ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
      :authentication       => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `smtp.zoho.eu` instead of `smtp.zoho.com` as address did the trick for me.